# What things (language...) I have to know if I want to work with SAP ERP

Tags: system, required, sap-erp

I have been very interested in the SAP ERP world and I would like to know what knowledge (programming languages or theories) I should know before studying or practicing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAP ERP is programmed in ABAP, some parts of other SAP Systems that interact with the ERP like SAP PO are programmed in Java.

So ABAP is the most important language and Java probably the second.